# The application (name) has stopped unexpectedly please try again

Tags: android

I am coding a switch statement for Android and I’m having trouble with the very first position. The other positions work fine, though. I have been trying for hours and still don’t see the problem. However, checking the Logcat I realized it is related to the main.xml.
This is my main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tech_g"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/smartphone"
        android:src="@drawable/pic_g" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tech_g2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the java:

```
package net.android.nameapp;
public class Smartphone extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.smartphone);
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSmartphone);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity (new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://www.vw/smartphone?&zipRdr=y")));
            }
        });
        }
}
```

I have defined all my classes in the Manifest file. Here is what the Logcat says:

```
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.android.nameapp/net.android.nameapp.Smartphone}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668):     at net.android.laptechgadgetsapp.Smartphone.onCreate(Smartphone.java:15)
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-12 10:34:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(2668):     ... 11 more
```

Here is the java:

```
package net.android.nameapp;
public class Smartphone extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.smartphone);
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSmartphone);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity (new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://www.vw/smartphone?&zipRdr=y")));
            }
        });
        }
}

package net.android.nameapp;
public class Main extends ListActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String[] gdgt={"Smartphone", "Laptop", "iPod","iPad", "Smartpen"};
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, R.id.tech_g2, gdgt));
        }
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
            switch(position){
            case 0:
                startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Smartphone.class));
                break;
```

Could you please shed some light here?

Comment: Yes all the activities are declared in the manifest file.

Comment: Okay y'all the thing is that the code is very long. I am posting the one are related to the error. This application is running except for the case's first position. So that's not it, because all the other positions just work fine.

Comment: is R.id.btnSmartphone button or imageview?

Answer (score 1):

//in your `smartphone.xml` you are declaring `ImageView` and in your `Smartphone`  activity you are calling as Button

Change it ImageView

```
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSmartphone);
```

to

```
ImageViewbtn1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnSmartphone);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is fine then delete your R file. (Don't worry it will be automatically generated again). Basically anything that makes your project rebuild and re-generate the R file.
Sometimes Eclipse tends to mess up resources. This leads to some odd behavior such as  classCastException(s), which happen when Eclipse switches your Views' ids around.